# How to set relationships using Sequelize `hasMany` with no/custom primary key

Tags: sequelize.js

Use case is I have "Tiles" on a page, and each tile could display for one or more "Devices" (browser, ios, android, etc). In SQL land, the is a `tile` table (`id`, `name`, `link`, ...), and a `tile_device_map` table (`tileId`, `device`), where `device` is an ENUM.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = new Sequelize('database', '', '', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: ':memory:',
    operatorsAliases: false,
});

const Tile = db.define('tile', {
    name: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING
});
const TileDeviceMap = db.define('tileDeviceMap', {
    tileId: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    device: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
Tile.hasMany(TileDeviceMap);

const tile = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Apple',
    tileDeviceMaps: [
        { device: 'ios' }
    ]
};

db.sync({ force: true })
    .then(() => {
        return Tile.create(tile, {
            include: [{ model: TileDeviceMap }]
        })
    })
    .then(result => {
        return Tile.findById(1, {
            include: [{ model: TileDeviceMap }]
        });
    })
    .then(result => {
        // console.log('RESULT', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        return result.setTileDeviceMaps([]);
    });
```

Creating the tile with device maps works fine. However, trying to remove all device maps throws an error. The SQL generated is as follows:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tileDeviceMaps`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiles`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tiles`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tiles` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`tiles`)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tileDeviceMaps`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tileDeviceMaps` (`tileId` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `tiles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `device` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`tileId`, `device`));
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`tileDeviceMaps`)
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_INFO(`sqlite_autoindex_tileDeviceMaps_1`)
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `tiles` (`id`,`name`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (1,'Apple','2018-02-15 07:56:27.225 +00:00','2018-02-15 07:56:27.225 +00:00');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `tileDeviceMaps` (`tileId`,`device`) VALUES (1,'ios');
Executing (default): SELECT `tile`.`id`, `tile`.`name`, `tile`.`createdAt`, `tile`.`updatedAt`, `tileDeviceMaps`.`tileId` AS `tileDeviceMaps.tileId`, `tileDeviceMaps`.`device` AS `tileDeviceMaps.device` FROM `tiles` AS `tile` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tileDeviceMaps` AS `tileDeviceMaps` ON `tile`.`id` = `tileDeviceMaps`.`tileId` WHERE `tile`.`id` = 1;
Executing (default): SELECT `tileId`, `device` FROM `tileDeviceMaps` AS `tileDeviceMap` WHERE `tileDeviceMap`.`tileId` = 1;
Executing (default): UPDATE `tileDeviceMaps` SET `tileId`=NULL WHERE `tileId` IN (1)
```

What's strange is the way Sequelize is trying to remove the relationship in the last query. I would have expected something like:

```
DELETE FROM `tileDeviceMaps` WHERE `tileId` IN (1)
```

Is there a way I can get the `hasMany` relationship to work or do I need to manually attend to updating relationships in my services? The problem seems to be stemming from the fact there is no normal primary key on the mapping table (but it's completely unnecessary).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a good resource help for Sequelize: http://sequelize.slack.com

Comment: @balexandre how do you get an invite to that?

Comment: it's free to access, just [request invitation](https://sequelize-slack.herokuapp.com/) and you're in!

Comment: [they wrote this](https://s6.postimg.org/f0i7nhtsx/screenshot_623.png) when pointed to your question, but join in and ask around

Comment: I believe what you actually want to do is destroy() and not set(). Set is an update call and that's why it's trying to set the id to null ( since nothing was passed in the array).

Comment: @chettyharish the set to an empty array is what is shown in the docs, hence why I'm trying that. If I add a standard `id` to the join table, it all works, but I'd prefer not to do that.